# Digitally sign all the packets from client machine

Tags: digital-signature

If I insist on digitally signing all outgoing packets from my computer, would it affect my browsing experience?
I mean if a website doesn't expect me to sign my packets, and still I sign them, can I access that website?
As the packet data is in plain text and only its hash is encrypted and attached with the data, I think the website should be ok with that. But I am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are confusing layer 3 with layer 7 and signing with SSL/TLS. It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean I sign all my messages using SSL. Would the websites be ok with that?

Comment: It's still completely unclear what you want. What's wrong with classic SSL/TLS?

Comment: It is a prototype project I am working on. Apologies for the confusion. I do not want to encrypt whole message using SSL. I just want to sign it. So message would go in plain but with digital signature. Question is that is it ok for websites?

Comment: @LucasKauffman I think the "problem" with "classic SSL/TLS" is that the user has no way to force it on when a website doesn't support it. Also, it's generally assumed that SSL/TLS always signs *and* encrypts - Xovie appears to recognize that the latter would cause issues with websites not configured to use it while, in theory, the former could just be discarded as junk data.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a lot! So my question is that would it work? Your comment suggests that it would work.

Comment: @Iszi it doesn't sign and encrypt every single packet, the session key is signed and encrypted.  Every packet is then encrypted with the session key.

Comment: True. But either way I want to keep message in plain text and sign it. I am thinking that the site could access the signature and trace the user even if he is anonymous. Food for thought..

Comment: @Xovie In theory, they could. In practice, they won't. Unless they're actively logging every last bit and byte that comes into their system, sites that don't care about digital signatures will just discard them and move on with their lives - again, zero security benefit to either party unless both parties are supporting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to force SSL/TLS - even without encryption - on websites and services that are not configured to use it, you will find that most of the Internet will be broken for you. For SSL/TLS to work, both ends of the connection must support it. Otherwise the connection negotiation will fail and your computer will treat the website as if it doesn't exist.

Besides that, the most basic problem with this idea is that it adds network and system overhead for absolutely zero security benefit. Digital signatures are only worth having if they're actually going to be verified. If a website is going to verify your signatures, it will be configured to support SSL/TLS. If SSL/TLS is not supported, there is no point in signing.

Comment: This clears up the confusion. Thanks. I am dabbling with some crazy ideas and this was very important problem. Cheers!

Comment: I understand that signing all messages would break the internet for me. I would like to implement this. Instead of signing, I can append some garbage data to each message and see what happens. Can you suggest some way to do this? I tried Tamper Data addon with Firefox to edit cookies and appended garbage at the end. Works fine.

Comment: @Xovie Regardless of how you're going to do this, or even if it's possible to do it without breaking the Internet for yourself, point #2 still stands. Unless a not-insignificant number of websites you use suddenly decide to implement verification of your home-grown signing protocol on their servers, there is zero benefit for you to do this.